# NSData's dataWithBytesNoCopy and writeToFile

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, file-io, nsdata

I have a category method that does somethign like this:

```
@implementation NSData (additions)
- (id)someFunc {

char *buffer = malloc(255);
NSUInteger length = 0;
while (true) {
    // . . . fill buffer[length++];
}

realloc(buffer, length);
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:length freeWhenDone:NO];
}
```

I am then trying to write the returned data (well call this NSData *fileData):

```
NSError *error;
NSData fileData = [NSData someFunc];
[fileData writeToFile:somePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

I get an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 512.)"
>   UserInfo=0x20deffd0
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/user/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/4C315580-153D-4FA7-9474-E17B58832515/Library/Caches/file.pdf,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x20de1fe0 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. Bad
>   address"}

The path exists and is valid. I think the issue is the returned NSData is just a light wrapper around an array allocated with malloc and that writeToFile does not know how to handle this. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to save the address returned by realloc: `buffer = realloc(buffer, length);`

Comment: @DarkDust That was the problem, please make that an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `realloc` you must save the returned pointer, since `realloc` may allocate a new buffer and copy the content of the old location to that new location. Afterwards the old location is `free`d and thus invalid. A different `malloc` call may overwrite that old location.

So you need to do:

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, length);
```

Comment: That won't work with the way OP's code is structured.  I.e. a `realloc()` after the loop does nothing useful.   And if the input data were too big for the original `malloc(255)`, then memory has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't make any sense.

- show the code that you use to fill the buffer
- you have a malloc(), why do you realloc() after the loop?  That is a waste of cycles and, if the goal were to expand the buffer if the input data were too long, it won't work as written.
- you must **check the return value** from `writeToFile:options:error:` to know whether or not there is an error;  you cannot check the error directly.
- also, don't stick a category like that onto an existing class.  In general, it is indicative of an architecture that is fragile and poorly layered.  If you do go this route, at least prefix your method with something unique.

It isn't clear why that particular error came up.   That path seems a little wonky maybe, how are you generating it?

Comment: The code to fill the buffer was unimportant in the end, but I could see how I should included it. realloc is called because it is decoding a base64 encoded string and the original buffer can be much larger than the actual used bytes in the end. I wasnt clear about how I read the error, but i did use writeToFile:options:error. And I don't personally use categories, the code was generated by Wsdl2Obj c, a tool that generates objective-c code from a webservice description. Thanks for attempting an answer still.

Comment: The use of realloc outside the loop made no sense, would likely lead to a memory smasher.  DarkDust's suggestion wouldn't work without restructuring the code (unless the data was smaller then the original buffer, rendering the realloc pointless).